# Moving site to a subdomain, .htaccess redirections Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a site at the address `http://example.com`, it has been configured to remove .html (.php, etc.) at the end of url and prevent from hot-linking events (except Search Engines).

I want to set up a multi-regional site with subdomains like `http://us-en.example.com` and move everything from my current site `http://example.com` to `http://us-en.example.com` completely.

I have several questions regarding `.htaccess` file:

Question 1

Example:
User have a "clear" link like this `http://example.com/images/all/image1`, but since I move everything this path contains no images and **didn't exist**.

How to set up a config file to redirect this "clean" url to a "default" subdomain (us-en), from `http://example.com/images/all/image1` to `http://us-en.example.com/images/all/image1`, but do nothing if link already contains a subdomain?

Question 2

How to set up `.htaccess` file properly for all subdomains to have the same features as the original one (removing .html/.php and prevent hot-linking)?

Question 3

How to do all of this from the template bellow?

```
DirectoryIndex home.html

Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !^https?://([^.]+\.)?example\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !search\?q=cache                 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !google\.                        [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !bing\.                          [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}     !yahoo\.                         [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: Yes, I do @DusanBajic

Comment: Are all your subdomain sites in separate folders?

Comment: Yes, they are @DusanBajic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not use .htaccess at all if you have access to apache configuration files (for detailed explanation look [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when))

Q1:

in .conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / https://us-en.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

or (if you don't want to use .conf files), put this on top of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://us-en.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

For other questions, there is nothing domain specific in your rules that would prevent them from being reused. You should only change (when moving rules from `.htaccess` to VirtualHost configuration)

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

since in VirtualHost context, the *Pattern* will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port (and before the query string) so you need leading `/` there

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, Can it all be done by .htaccess only?

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Wold I mind if I may ask you some follow up here, later, when I be implementing it? (I’m on mobile now)

Comment: Do I have to create new .htaccess file for every single subdomain that I create or I  just can have one file in my main directory that will cover all my needs (Q1, Q2)? @Dusan Bajic

Comment: The point is how do I set up a default `home` (or `404`, `etc.`) page for every subdomain? Now I use this `DirectoryIndex home.html` in main .htaccess file in the example above. Can I somehow write a rule in main file to that to avoid making new files for every subdomain? @Dusan Bajic

Comment: And a last one, how do I handle external css and script files and media (images, video, etc.) linked in pages (ex: my-css-file.css, my-scrypt-file.js)? I want to avoid changing patches one every page. What is a propper way to do that? Dusan Bajic